Distance between subspaces after premultiplication by diagonal matrice
Let $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ be two k dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and two $n\times K$ matrices $E_1$,$E_2$ are basis matrix. Distance between two subspaces is defined to be the square root of sum of principal angles between them.
Suppose $\text{dist}(\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2)=\delta$. Let $A=\text{diag}(x_1,....,x_n)$ with $x_1\geq x_2...\geq x_n>0$. What is the maximum value of $\text{dist}(\text{span}(AE_1),\text{span}(AE_2))$?

Suppose $\delta$ is very small. The maximum value means an upper bound with $\delta$.
